# Different Sources of MessageEvent

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If I do window.postMessage() from webpage, the content script will get "message" event in which case MessageEvent.source === window.

What are the different situations in which MessageEvent.source !== window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When another window or frame dispatches the message, e.g.:

```js
// Example: Another window:
window.opener.postMessage(' ... ' , '*');
var win = window.open();
win.onload = function() {
    win.postMessage(' ... ', '*');
};

// Example: Another frame
window.top.postMessage(' ... ', '*');
window.frames[0].postMessage(' ... ', '*');
window.parent.postMessage(' ... ', '*'); // etc.
```

Comment: Can there be a situation where MessageEvent.source === window but MessageEvent.origin !== window.location.origin ?

Comment: @KrishnaSrinivas No, that is not possible.